# A dead loop test in uboot

Tags: assembly, arm, u-boot

```
.globl _start
_start: bl      dead_loop
        ldr     pc, _start
        ldr     pc, _undefined_instruction
        ldr     pc, _software_interrupt
        ldr     pc, _prefetch_abort
        ldr     pc, _data_abort
        ldr     pc, _not_used
        ldr     pc, _irq
        ldr     pc, _fiq

dead_loop:
        nop
        mov pc, lr
```

I want to do a uboot dead loop test, but found it jumps out of the supposed loop, What's wrong with my code, it is in start.S.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test for lack of an ARM crosscompiler right now, but you simply seem to be missing an `=`. Use

```
ldr pc, =_start
```

if what you want is to "jump to immediate". Otherwise, the assembler will treat the above as equal to `ldr pc, [ pc, ... ]` which is quite probably not what you want.

Note the difference between the `ADR` and `LDR` pseudo-instructions; `adr pc, _start` would, in your case, do the same as `ldr pc, =start`.